# Xcode Repositry Git Error

Tags: xcode, github, bitbucket, iphone-sdk-4.1

Please review the screen shot, and let me know how can i fix this? I am using my computer and this configuration from last 1 year and I have no issue, It is suddenly happen.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You seem to try to commit/push to a remote repository, while you haven't yet given git your identity/email address + password.
The steps to do this are already stated in the error message:
Just open up Terminal and enter the two commands:

```
git config --global user.email "youremail@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

You'll be prompted for your password several times. To cache your password follow the instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/